# AutoHotKey - How to Reference Files in Current Directory?

Tags: autohotkey

Newbie question here. I used Pulover's Macro Recorder to create my AHK script, and I'm trying to amend the AHK script itself to work on other's computers. Right now, when I reference image files, the file path to the image only works on my computer due to my username being in the filepath ("C:\Users\windowshopr\ahk_project\images\image.png"), but what I'm looking to do is change those file paths, so that it just references a folder within the current script's working directory.

At the beginning of the script, I have `SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%` defined, so all file references should be relative to that. What I want to do is just reference the "images\image.png" part, so that as long as the other users have that images folder, it'll work on their machines as well, I just don't know the syntax for this and I've tried a few different solutions online, but I think I'm getting it wrong.

What's the correct way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply with the relative path.

**In your case:**
If your .ahk file sits in `C:\Users\windowshopr\ahk_project` and you have set `SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%` you actually reference `C:\Users\windowshopr\ahk_project\images\image.png` with `images\image.png`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still stumbling through trying to figure out the syntax of AHK. I also learned that some functions don't need parentheses around the directories and some do, that's what I was missing in my code. Anyway, thank you! Worked!